# Printing deepcopy of an object using custom function

Tags: javascript

I need to print elements of an object which is a deepcopy of another object using custom function. I am able  to  create deep copy using JSON parse/stringify trick but unable to implement print function.

```
    var obj = {a:1,
        b:{
            a:2,
            c:[1,2,3],
            d:{
                a:3
            }
        }
    };

const mySnapShot = new Snapshot(object);

mySnapshot.print('a')// 1
    .print('b.c') //[1,2,3]
    .print('b.a') // 2
```

Arguments passed in print method are string. Snapshot is a class which contains methods for deep copy and print.

Comment: And what is the problem/ error that you are having and what is snapshot?

Comment: Snapshot  is a class which contains methods for deep  copy  and printing values.  I am able to create  deep  copy in the constructor but unable  to implement print method.

Comment: What have you tried for the print method, and what problems did you encounter that you need help with ?

Comment: unable to process string arguments

Comment: you could just `split` on `.` and then a simple loop on the resulting array would suffice for getting to the property you want.

Comment: Such designs usually make no sense. Why have a String that separates back into Object properties? Use the regular dot access instead.

Comment: Do you need to implement the print(path) method?

Comment: yeah, implement print('path') method

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli thanks,your approach worked as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reduce:

```js
var obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: {
        a: 2,
        c: [1, 2, 3],
        d: {
            a: 3
        }
    }
};

function print(path) {
    const pathTokens = path.split('.');
    const pathValue = pathTokens.reduce((subObj, pathToken) => {
        return subObj && subObj[pathToken] || null
    }, obj);
    return pathValue;
}

console.log(print('a')) // 1
console.log(print('b.c')) //[1,2,3]
console.log(print('b.a')) // 2
```